# java.lang.IllegalStateException in playstore crashes (only on Android 8.0)

Tags: java, android

i am getting crash reports at google play console.
i can see it happens with only on Android 8.0 only.. not even any other single devices.

The log is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity 
  (ActivityThread.java:2858)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity 
  (ActivityThread.java:2933)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage 
  (ActivityThread.java:1612)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6710)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
  (Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:770)

  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.Activity.onCreate (Activity.java:986)
  at com.shravanvinu.stockscreener.TrendActivity.onCreate 
  (TrendActivity.java:44)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6982)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate 
  (Instrumentation.java:1214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity 
  (ActivityThread.java:2811)
```

I dont see it wen i run in debug or release mode from android studio. 
but i can see lot of such crashes everyday on play store reports.

To be specific. this is a custom Dialog activity called from in my main activity.

App level gradle file

```
    buildscript {
      repositories {
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:        [0.11.0, 0.99.99]'
       }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

    repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.shravanvinu.stockscreener"
    manifestPlaceholders = [
            onesignal_app_id               : 'b3223944-9679-4fed-a192-         3f316321a794',
            // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is 
    ignored.
            onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
    ]
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 18
    versionName "4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
   'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'

    implementation files('libs/coollection.jar')
    implementation 'com.github.anastr:speedviewlib:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

i was using app compact, now change to android x in this release.

Comment: What is `TrendActivity.java:44` line code ?

Comment: Show your activity where the stack trace leads to. Also, most of the time such crashes occur in release build because some classes belonging to the third-party library get ignored while compilation. That being said, show your app level Gradle file if you are using any 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @Stanislav Bondar 44- super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
45- requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
46- setContentView(R.layout.activity_trend);

Comment: @Taseer please check the added gradle file.

Comment: ```at com.shravanvinu.stockscreener.TrendActivity.onCreate 
  (TrendActivity.java:44)``` review this line of code

Comment: @ShravanRavi Did you change activity theme as NoActionBarTitile in manifest?

Comment: @Nithin   <activity
            android:name=".TrendActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />

Comment: @Nithin-- protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trend);

Comment: 44 line- is the 1st line of oncreate.. super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: i went through all the logs again.. i can see it happening only on Android 8.0 devices.. irrespective of manufacturers..